# How can i deploy my react.js project on heroku without webpack

Tags: reactjs, heroku, redux

I have allready completed my project but its just normal project without webpack and babel.

I am facing problem in deploying to Heroku.

My projects works fine locally but when i post it to heroku.

it gives me this error 
"Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'circular-json'
 @ multi main" on my mai  page.

My main page looks like this

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import store from './Store/AppStore';
    import './index.css';
    import { createStore } from 'redux';
    import loginconatiner from './Components/Containers/Login';
    import list from './Components/Containers/Recoderings';
    import { hashHistory } from 'react-router';
   import {Link, browserHistory, Router, Route  } from "react-router";
    var CircularJSON = require('circular-json')

  render(


<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <div>
        <Route path="/" component={loginconatiner}/>
        <Route path="/Rec" component={list}/>
        </div>
    </Router>
</Provider>,
document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: sorry man... it didn't work for me...